# Override Drupal Node Template

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I want to change the layout of some nodes on my Drupal 7 site - namely to have the fields display across the page.  In reading up on theming, they seem to be saying that in order to override node.tpl.php, I need to have my own them?

Is there a way of using an existing them (e.g. Bartik), but just simply overriding it for node layouts by using a custom **node--mytype.tpl.php** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal you can [create a sub theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) that extends another theme.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can copy existing node.tpl.php and rename it to node--page.tpl.php. This template after clearing cache(Configuration->Performance) will be applyed to te nodes of type Page. Same thing you can do for Article node type with node--artcle.tpl.php or for any other. During manual update of the core to the new version theese files will not be replaced. But better to create a your own theme in 'sites/all/themes/' folder (Maybe child of Batric theme if needed).